# Как сделать так, чтобы было сравнение строки из массива с полем UITextField при вводе каждого символа?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uikit

Добрый день.
Необходимо сравнить строку из массива с UITextField, чтобы выдало TRUE, только когда будет введено правильно слово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объекта класса `UITextField` нужно указать делегат, например, текущий класс:

```
self.textField.delegate = self;
```

У текущего класса нужно реализовать метод `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` делегата [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // Будет вызван каждый раз, когда меняется хотя бы один символ в текстфилде.
    return YES;
}
```

Из официальной документации:

> Text field вызывает этот метод каждый раз, когда пользователь вводин
>   новый символ или удаляет существующий.

Comment: @Yurjke пожалуйста! Если ответ помог, то плюсаните его, пожалуйста, и пометьте как правильный. :)

Comment: плюсанул, написало, что + добавится только тогда,когда наберется репутация 15 :))